# Retriev variable values in javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am using facebook API for my project and getting some data in following manner in var `mydata`

```
if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
            FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) { //--
            console.log(mydata);
              if(data.email == null)
              {
                 alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                 ResetAnimate();
             }
   }
```

I dont have any issue with this code. But I want to send this data using ajax call to process and insert into database.

My ajax call:

```
function AjaxResponse()
 {
    var send=document.ge(mydata)      **//Here I want to fetch mydata from previous code**
    var datas = document.elements['id'].value;
    var s = 'connect=1'; 
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_facebook.php",
    data: s,send                   **//Is this correct way to send s and send togather? I have tried with only 's' which works fine but dont know about both togather**
    }).done(function(result) {
    $("#fb-root").html(result);
    });
   }
```

Can someone please assist how to fetch mydata in javascript function and review the code.

Comment: Just call `AjaxResponse` inside the `FB.api` callback and pass `mydata` to it. Of course you also have to define `AjaxResponse` to accept an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Facebook API call you're making is asynchronous, you *can't* return the value from your `ge` function.

Instead, use a callback, just like Facebook and everyone else does. See below.

Separately, the answer to the second unrelated question hidden in your code snippet is "no, that's not how you do that". I've given you a pointer to how to do that below as well.

```
function AjaxResponse()
{
    // Callback here----v arg ---v
    document.ge(mydata, function(send) {
        var datas = document.elements['id'].value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_facebook.php",
            data: {
               connect: 1,
               paramname: mydata      // <=== I don't know what the name of this param is
            }
        }).done(function(result) {
        $("#fb-root").html(result);
    });
}
```

..and have your code call the callback when the Facebook call calls *its* callback.

```
function ge(data, callback) {
    // ...
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
        FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function (mydata) { //--
            console.log(mydata);
            if (data.email == null) {
                alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                ResetAnimate();
            }
            else {
                callback(data); // <=== Trigger the callback
            }
        }
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, but now I get this error - ` ReferenceError: LodingAnimate is not defined `

Comment: I was really not knowing the concept you told!

Comment: @Karimkhan: That would be unrelated to this question. You just need to make sure that function is in scope. The changes I made above should affect whether it's in scope for that code.

Comment: your answer gave me right direction, but it was giving `TypeError : callback(data) is not defined at callback(data); `

Comment: you pointer out me in code, but probably I could not understand it!